# Trouble running Hello world Project

Tags: android

I'm having difficulty to run a simple hello world project on AVD. In the console it says:

```
"[2014-07-14 21:32:56 - TryApp] Installing TryApp.apk...
[2014-07-14 21:35:09 - TryApp] Failed to install TryApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-07-14 21:35:09 - TryApp] (null)
[2014-07-14 21:35:09 - TryApp] Launch canceled!"
```

Also when i first created the project the console had some warnings:

```
"[2014-07-14 21:26:01 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Marcatus X\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-07-14 21:26:01 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Marcatus X\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache"
```

I believe I installed eclipse and adt correctly. The ADT bundle had some issues so i had to download everything separately and put them in the same folder. The eclipse says its Luna, and installed the latest Android SDK tools 23.0.2.

I would appreciate any help to get me going in Android development.

Here is the logcat errors:

```
07-15 02:48:47.680: I/Process(834): Sending signal. PID: 834 SIG: 9
07-15 02:51:16.800: D/AndroidRuntime(876): Shutting down VM
07-15 02:51:16.800: W/dalvikvm(876): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception        (group=0xb3ac5d70)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876): Process: com.example.tryapp, PID: 876
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tryapp/com.example.tryapp.MainActivity}:    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action  bar.
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876): Caused by:  android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at com.example.tryapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-15 02:51:16.840: E/AndroidRuntime(876):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you able to launch the emulator separately?

Comment: yes...right now the emulator is still running.

Comment: Alright, I started the emulato seperately...then raaaan the project. At first it says " success" but i did not see anything on the emulator. So i press the run button again;                            The emulator said " unfortunately first app has stopped' the it say something about logcat monitoring error

Comment: If the app runs successfully on your AVD, then you should see your app icon in the application page, try to run your app if it has not started itself. By the way these errors are common when you use virtual devices in ADT. Sometimes it depends on your device configuration like RAM, Android version, etc. I recommend using standard devices which ADT provides.

Comment: If you see the error "Unfortunately your app has stopped". Then you have some problem in your app and it is nothing wrong with the emulator. Try to check logCat or errors and handle them.

Comment: I posted the logcat errors..I'm not sure how to fix it. Note I'm ruining simply a "hello world" project. I did not change anything when i creed the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing target sdk version to 19

Do not use API Level of 20 and Platform 4.4W, as Android Virtual Device. With Level 19 and Platform 4.2.2 set on ADV everything runs as it should.

Comment: Alright, I downloaded API 19 and  and some extra stuff on the SDK manager  to i try the app app as u instructed. When i restart eclipse it gives me this error: "Running Android Lint" has encountered a problem---details=Failed
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I created a new project then assigned the target and compile sdk to 19. I also made a new virtual device with AP19 as target. It Worked!!!! My first working Hello world project!!! I thank you for your help. Though that means I cant use API 20 or L preview...

I changed the "android version to use when rendering layout in Eclipse" to 19 is that ok??

Also what about the error I got when restarting Eclipse: "Running Android Lint" has encountered a problem---details=Failed java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: @Marcatus The main cause f this error is some sort of invalid project definition. I mean one or more of the class path entries are pointing to a resource which can't be opened; for example, you might have a classpath reference which is relative to a class path variable, and the class path variable is no longer pointing to an absolute location. I am glad that your project has been running eventually but in future whenever you encounter this kinds of errors try this: On My Project -> Context Menu -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.

Comment: @Marcatus If my answer solved your problem, please choose it as the answer.

Comment: I thank for your help. Where do i find this set of menu "On My Project -> Context Menu -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties" I look on the menu bar i can find them

Comment: @Marcatus right click on your project, in the list choose Android Tools->Fix Project Properties.